# BIOS Corrupted After A Failed Suspension

Tags: 12.04, boot, uefi, battery

Currently typing from a friend's Wii. My HP 2000-299WM laptop stalled while suspending one night, so I forced it to shutdown with the power button.

Now, initial HP splash screen is blank, and leads me to a non-blinking underscore, (Frozen?) which stays locked up.

I am currently unsure if the bios settings are corrupted, or if the UEFI loader, if the splashscreen is one, is broken. Because I have tried many methods to clear the CMOS by removing the bios battery, which means disassembling my laptop multiple times to access it, and it doesn't work.

The battery itself is not dead either. I hooked it up to a small electric motor, and it received power.

I also did the caps lock LED test, and it gave me two blinks, signifying bios corruption instead of a hardware problem. The GPU, CPU, RAM, fan, HDD, and wireless card were operating at their best without any sign of degradation before this happened, so it's telling me that the hardware is likely okay. I have owned this laptop for two years without any issues previously.

How do I reset the CMOS on my laptop model, if that's the issue, or does it go deeper that? I am so short on answers at the moment, and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot, but it sounds like your machine might be making it past the BIOS and then just hanging at boot. My MBP used to do this. Had something to do with not being able to resume from the memdisk when booting from EFI. Every boot would take me to the same screen you're getting.

If this is the case, and you are indeed getting through the BIOS, think you could manage it to boot from CD? If so, you could burn a copy of Super Grub Disc 2 and boot up with that. It'll find your exisiting GRUB install. Edit that to include `acpi_sleep=nonvs` before the `quiet splash` params and then boot up. That'll force your Ubuntu to wake from its slumber.